# Using Regex to match all characters but break at comma semicolon and newline

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a box that the user will enter part numbers into and I am wanting to make it so they can either write it out in a line using comma or semicolon breaks (this; style;|or, this, style) but can also use carriage returns and make the list in the textbox. I have an pattern that works great for all i need EXCEPT breaking at new line ((\w+\s*[\p{P}\p{S}-[;,]]*\s*)+) i have tried numerous combinations of (\r\n|\r|\n). I have tried using single line format. Nothing has worked and i cannot find anything on how to break at newline.

Below is the sub that is handling this:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_TextChanged(sender as object, e as TextChangedEventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.TextChanged
    Dim pattern As String = "(\w+\s*[\p{P}\p{S}-[;,]]*\s*)+"
        MyListBox.Items.Clear()
        For Each Match As Match In Regex.Matches(DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text, pattern)
            If Match.Value.Length > 20 Then
                MyListBox.Items.Add(Match.Value.Remove(20))
            Else
                MyListBox.Items.Add(Match.Value)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

This works great for all except breaking at newlines.

Comment: It's `\n` not `/n`. Try `[;,\n]` in your regex.

Comment: sorry mistype i editted

Comment: You need to provide sample input for both what it should match and what it should NOT if you want help.

Comment: The regex in the question features a a very nice example of **character class subtraction**, I've upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\s` matches a newline symbol. You need to only match horizontal whitespace.

Replace `\s` with `\p{Zs}`.

```
(\w+\p{Zs}*[\p{P}\p{S}-[;,]]*\p{Zs}*)+
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cw%2B%5Cp%7BZs%7D*%5B%5Cp%7BP%7D%5Cp%7BS%7D-%5B%3B%2C%5D%5D*%5Cp%7BZs%7D*)%2B&i=this%3B%20style%3B%7Cor%2C%20this%2C%20style%0D%0Amore)

With

```
this; style;|or, this, style
more
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: That works great, thanks. I will accept once it lets me.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, the line endings at regexstorm.net are of CRLF type. And a very nice example of character class subtraction, good for you! :)